# Remove Duplicate Files with Bash Script on Network Share

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

To prevent this from being closed, I have narrowed my question to just the bash script.

**EDITED QUESTION**

I run a small network and made a mistake in a backup routine. I have `rsync` running daily, and how it is set up is that if a folder is renamed on the source, then potential duplication on the backup device can occur.

`rsync -varz --no-perms --exclude-from=/path/to/exclude_file --log-file=/path/to/rsync_logs`

Recently a user made quite a few changes, and it resulted in a lot of duplication.

What kind of bash script strategies can I use to attack this? I've tried listing recursively and outputting to files and using `diff` to compare these. This has lead me to see the impact of the duplication problem. If I could use some kind of automated process to remove the duplicates, that would save me loads of time.

I started by trying something like this:

`find /mnt/data/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' > data.txt`

and comparing to:

`find /mnt/backup/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' > backup.txt`

An example of my problem is this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 bob staff  0 Jun 25  2009 7-1-08
drwxr-xr-x 0 bob staff  0 Jun 25  2009 2008-07-01
```

This is an example from the backup drive, and the two directories are identical in their contents. The backup contains both and the source has only this one:

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 bob staff  0 Jun 25  2009 2008-07-01
```

This kind of issue is all throughout the backup drives.

**EDIT**

I created two lists and `diff`ed them and then went through manually and reconciled the changes. It wasn't as bad as I originally thought, once I got into it. I gave +1s to both answers here (@Mark Pettit and @ebarrere), because I did end up using pieces from each answer. I ran several find commands in the course of this experiment and I ended up altering my `rsync` script as well, to be more specific. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with @Mark's suggestion to fix the `rsync` script, you could use a `find` with `exec` to find duplicate files.  Something like this:

```
cd /mnt/data
find . -type f -exec bash -c "ls /mnt/backup/'{}' &> /dev/null && echo /mnt/backup/'{}'" \;
```

would echo any files that exist in the same path under both directories.  The path printed will be to the file in the backup directory.  You could change the `echo` to an `rm -f` to remove the files, but be careful with that.

Comment: This is a great little command. Thanks for helping me out. I tested this on several subdirectories in which I knew duplicates were present and it found them. I could verify this manually, so it was very trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

You should fix this by fixing your rsync script, not by writing a new bash script.

If your source is clean, and it's only your backup destination that's messed up, you can easily clean up the destination by adding "--delete" to your list of arguments to "rsync". That flag tells rsync to delete any directories on the destination that do not exist on the source.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good idea and I might be able to use it in some form, although there is so much data that it might take too long and collide with the next day's activities... And, in general, I don't want to use `--delete` because I don't want to clobber data that is important. There is a reason I set it up not to delete in the destination.